# How to create a subversion repository with standard layout?

Tags: svn, repository

Is it possible to create a new SVN repository which is automatically structured by the SVN standard repository layout (trunk, branches, tags) via commandline (svnadmin create)?

Or do I always have to create thos directories manually?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since it is only a suggested layout it doesn't do that out of the box. If you are using linux, here is a simple script I use for that:

```
#!/bin/bash
url=svn://somewhere
svn mkdir $url/$1/trunk $url/$1/branches $url/$1/tags -m "New project $1" --parents
```

Comment: Thank you and the other answerers. This solution might fit best for me.

Comment: cooleo :-) i used to do the mkdir - but i didnt know i could do all three together in one command. Thanks! This is an effort-saver for a lazybone like me :-)

Answer (score 4):

What I do is after creating the repository, I import a separate directory called SVNtmp that already has trunk/branches/tags in it.  Don't know of anyway to automatically do this.

Comment: `svn import /path/to/some/skeleton/dir` is indeed the fastest way I know without have to create a checkout, copy the skeleton, and committing it

Comment: svnadmin create <repositoryName>
svn import /Data/VisualSvnRepositories/SVNtmp file:///Data/VisualSvnRepositories/<repositoryName>  -m "Initial structure."  I was struggling with volume names, tried to add that into the PATH and URL parameters. Finally code below worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You have to remember that there are (at least) two standard layouts, the choice of which depends on what's most appropriate to your projects:

```
/
  /trunk
     /project1
     /project2
  /branches
  /tags
```

or

```
/
  /project1
    /trunk
    /branches
    /tags
  /project2
    /trunk
    /branches
    /tags
```

SVN is totally flexible about how you lay out the repository which is why it doesn't create a default layout.

Answer (score 1):

[subversion edge](http://www.open.collab.net/go/csvne2_r2a/) has a similar feature built in. Also some additional administration features. You might want to give it a try.